# how to write private methods of combobox in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I need to apply special css for selected combo values so I want to add class in `combo.el` therefore I wanted to use `onRender` method of combobox but not sure How to write. I am not getting hold in listener so Can any one please help me to solve this.

I tried :

```
H1 = {
xtype: 'combobox',
valueField: 'title',
displayField: 'title',
parentGrid : me,
dataIndex:header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX"),
queryMode: 'local',
multiSelect: true,
delimiter : ";",
isFilterDataLoaded: false,
listeners:{
    focus: me.onComboFilterFocus,
    //onRender : me.onRender // Not getting hold here.
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Listeners code with below lines.

```
 listeners:{
        focus : function(me, eOpts)
        {           
        },
        render : function (me, eOpts)
        {
          // You can add  alert or debugger here..
          // alert('Hi');
          // In case if you want to debug this in IE or Chrome add debugger
          // debugger; 

        }
    }
```

Comment: Debugger is not opening. Not actually it is working.

Comment: No for some reason it is not going there.